# What zeolite types are typically used to absorb CO and CO2 gases at maximum zeolite absorption temperature?

Tags: purification, filtering

Me and my friends are doing a project involving carbon monoxide and carbon dioxide as products to be filtered, we are using zeolites and would like to know the zeolite type typically used to filter $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}.$

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's better to take a moment to describe what you know based on information you have read or searched already. Stack Exchange shouldn't be your "first stop". If you have identified at least some zeolite materials that can do this as proof of principle, you should mention it *in your question*. Thanks!

Comment: NASA uses lithium hydroxide and silver oxide to remove CO2, but I'm not sure about the effectiveness for CO. Why zeolites? https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32177/12102 and also this PDF https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/2346/74151/ICES_2018_180.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: My apologies, uhoh. I have researched the question however I was unable to find information on zeolites that would typically be used to filter CO and CO2. However thank you for the information on Lithium Hydroxide and Silver Oxides!

Comment: @uhoh The idea of using zeolithes is to have an easily reversible (by simply changing the pressure) adsorption. It's a well introduced method for gas separation. LiOH *absorbs* CO2, and you need an energy-intensive chemistry to get it back out again.

Comment: @Karl I [see what you mean](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/current-and-near-future-space-suit-odor-reduction-technology/32177?noredirect=1#comment115085_32177)!